# Is it possible to print `traceback.format_exc()` in color using colored-traceback.py

Tags: python, colors, traceback

I am logging output of `traceback.format_exc()`.  Is it possible to color it using
[colored-traceback.py](https://github.com/staticshock/colored-traceback.py) while using print or alternative?

Example code:

```py
import traceback
import colored_traceback
colored_traceback.add_hook(always=True)

a = 1 / 0  # prints colored traceback results 
try:
    a = 1 / 0
except:
    traceback.print_exc()  # prints in color white
    print(traceback.format_exc())  # prints in color white
```

Comment: `traceback` [does its own printing](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/traceback.py) so the regular exception handling is not used – which, in turn, is what `colored_trackback` uses. It seems you need to combine the code of `colored_traceback` and `traceback.py` then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`colored_traceback`](https://github.com/staticshock/colored-traceback.py) looks useful, but I think it's overkill for your goal. You can achieve the desired effect with the [`pygments`](https://github.com/pygments/pygments) library and a few lines of code:

```py
import traceback

from pygments import formatters, highlight, lexers


try:
    a = 1 / 0
except:
    tb_text = "".join(traceback.format_exc())

    lexer = lexers.get_lexer_by_name("pytb", stripall=True)
    formatter = formatters.get_formatter_by_name("terminal256")
    tb_colored = highlight(tb_text, lexer, formatter)

    print(tb_colored)
```